# How to get the substituted text of perl (s//)?

Tags: perl, substitution

I use the following code to do substitution. Is there a way to retrieve the text substituted? In this example, I want to get the string `_5p_outsuffix.txt`.

```
/tmp$ ./main.pl 
xxx_5p_outsuffix.txt
/tmp$ cat main.pl 
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $filename="xxx_5p_insuffix.txt";
my $insuffix="_((5|3)p)_insuffix\.txt";
my $outsuffix = '_$1_outsuffix.txt';

$filename =~ s/$insuffix$/qq{"$outsuffix"}/ee;
print "$filename\n";
```

Answer (score 4):

You should *capture* the match string:

```
$filename =~ s/($insuffix)$/qq{"$outsuffix"}/ee;
print "$filename\n";
print "Substituted: $1\n";
```

Since this introduces an extra level of braces, you will have to adjust the numbers of any captures used in the replacement string. Alternatively you could the built-in `${^MATCH}` variable that contains the string matched by the last successful regex using the `/p` modifier. This would look like

```
$filename =~ s/$insuffix$/qq{"$outsuffix"}/eep;
print "$filename\n";
print "Substituted: ${^MATCH}\n";
```

(You *shouldn't* use `$&` for this purpose as it makes all regular expressions in the program substantially slower.)

Comment: What if he is already relying on the parentheses inside `$insuffix`? He would have to reindex his $1, $2 variables.

Comment: To use `${^MATCH}`, he would need the /p modifier, in addition to the /ee.

Comment: Regarding the last parenthetical in the answer, I'd suggest the reader to check out the 'Performance issues' section under http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#Variables-related-to-regular-expressions , and see how much this issue applies to their Perl version. Specifically, "In Perl 5.20.0 a new copy-on-write system was enabled by default, which finally fixes all performance issues with these three variables, and makes them safe to use anywhere."

Comment: @sundar: Since it's still rare to find version 5.20 in the wild, this is an unlikely scenario. It's also wise to remember that anything you write could at some point find itself running on a very different system under a much older version of Perl.

Answer (score 1):

check the section about Variables Related to Regular Expressions in [perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html) in particular the variable `$&`